# Compiling with XeLaTeX

Tags: errors, xetex

Everytime I try to compile a document with XeLaTeX, I get these errors

> ligne 1767: Forbidden control sequence found while scanning use of __cs_generate_from_signature:nnNNNn. \int_case:nnn
>
> ligne 1767: Undefined control sequence. \int_case:nnn
>   : LaTeX error: "kernel/deprecated-command" The deprecated command '\int_case:nnn' has been or will be removed on 2015-07-14. Use instead '\int_case:nnF '.
>
> ligne 1767: You can't use `macro parameter character #' in vertical mode. \int_case:nnn #
>
> ligne 1767: Missing \begin{document}. \int_case:nnn #2
>
> ligne 1772: Too many }'s. }
>
> ligne 1773: Too many }'s. }
>
> ligne 1774: Too many }'s. }
>
> ligne 2053: Undefined control sequence. \luatex_if_engine:T
>   : LaTeX error: "kernel/deprecated-command" The deprecated command '\luatex_if_engine:T' has been or will be removed on 2017-01-01. Use instead '\sys_if_engine_luatex:T '.
>
> ligne 76: Overfull \hbox (1.46pt too wide) in paragraph
>
> ligne 11: Overfull \hbox (28.25247pt too wide) in alignment

Does anyone know how to fix them ?

To compile, I use TexStudio with MikTex.

Thanks

An exemple of document which produces these errors is

```
    \documentclass[12pt, openany]{report}
    \usepackage[a4paper,left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
    \usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
    \usepackage{libertine}

    \setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
    \setlength{\parskip}{1ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.2ex}
    \newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{20pt}}
    \newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
    \newcommand{\mb}{\medbreak}
    \newcommand{\bb}{\bigbreak}
    \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
    \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
    \newcommand{\tit}[1]{\textit{#1}}
    \newcommand{\tb}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
    \newcommand{\ra}{\rightarrow}
    \newcommand{\hl}{\line(1,0){250}}
    \newcommand{\itemb}{\item[$ \bullet $]}
    \newcommand{\sss}[1]{\hsp \tb{#1} \mb}
    \newcommand{\grad}{\overrightarrow{grad} \ }
    \newcommand{\rot}{\overrightarrow{rot} \ }
    \newcommand{\vect}[1]{\overrightarrow{#1} }
    \newcommand{\fig}[4]{
        \begin{center}
            \includegraphics[scale=#1]{#2} \\
            Figure #3 : #4
        \end{center}
    }

    \newenvironment{demo}
    {
        \begin{center}
            Démonstration \\
            \hl \\
        \end{center}
    }
    {
        \begin{center}
            \hl \mb
        \end{center}
    }

    \begin{document}
        content
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a minimal compilable code that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Looks like the l3kernel packages etc. must be updated here

Comment: theer was a change some months ago to `\int_case:nnn ` you seem to have inconsistent files, some expecting the old  code and some the new, just updating your installation should fix things. As far as I understand miktex, You may need to update in admin and user mode, depending on how you installed things.

Comment: I add an exemple of a document which produces these errors. I've also installed the lastest version of texstudio but the errors still occur.

Comment: @JohnK Try to update your tex distribution - this is probably either texlive or miktex (texstudio is just an editor)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was caused by old packages and solved upon updating